# Dotenv-webpack in production?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack, dotenv

I am trying to use the [`dotenv-webpack`](https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack) plugin. This works great locally. But fails when I deploy to Heroku.

I have followed advice according to this [git issue](https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack/issues/121), but still am having issues.

My webpack config looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, '/src'),

  entry: {
    javascript: './js/index'
  },

output: {
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
},

resolve: {
  alias: {
    react: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react')
  },
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
},

module: {
  rules: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loaders: ['babel-loader'],
  },
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]',
  },
 ],
},
plugins: [
  new Dotenv({
    path: path.resolve(__dirname,'.env')
  }),
 ]
};
```

I am expecting that where the `dotenv` plugin is written as above, it will resolve my `.env` file (which is located at the root of the project, along with the webpack.config) upon build time, thus giving my project access to env vars. Instead, the env vars are `undefined`, in Heroku. I have an env var set in Heroku. The Key is set to something like `SECRET_KEY`. Value is set to something like `123456`. Can anyone give me some insight?

Comment: you can set your env vars in the heroku dashboard for production...

Comment: @SakoBu Hey thanks for replying. I did actually. Maybe I am not matching them right?

My .env file looks something like:

SECRET_KEY=123456

In my Heroku Dashboard I have key set to SECRET_KEY and value set to 123456. Does that make sense?

Comment: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/126  .env to Prod NOT REcommend on heroku.  Set config vars is what they recommend for ENV settings.

Answer (score 11):

I don't use Heroku and I have not tried it. But I understand that if you defined the variables at Heroku dashboard, then those variables are system variables, so you need to use the option `systemvars: true` of "dotenv-webpack".

As declaration (I repeat, I never used Heroku):
All this depends on how works the Heroku deploys, if you build the application inside of Heroku (you call to Webpack inside Heroku) then it works but if you send the built application to Heroku (you don't call to Webpack inside of Heroku) then it doesn't work.

Comment: `systemvars: true` helped me out. `dotenv-webpack` parsed the system env variables and embedded them into the app

Answer (score 4):

I think you can set up a custom webpack plugin instead.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack')
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
         'API_KEY': JSON.stringify(process.env.API_KEY)
      }
    })
  ]
};
```

Like these samples in your `webpack.prod.js` file.

Comment: Or you can use `new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin` and pass directly your object with the variables' names

Comment: @OLUWATOSIN.A AKINYELE: For some reason, my `webpack.config.js` is unable to see `process.env.API_KEY` from `.env` file (or any value from this file). Do you know why? To make it work I had to insert the value right there in the line:

'API_KEY': JSON.stringify('my_value_here')

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this issue comes from the environment values of the Heroku server. because in production mode `dotenv` call the real environment variable, I mean this:

```
echo $SECRET_KEY
```

But it returns `undefined`, why? because in the production mode the `.env` file won't be seen. so if you are serious about using the [`dotenv-webpack`](https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack) plugin you should pass the `path` for development just like your code:

```
plugins: [
  new Dotenv({
    path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env'),
  }),
 ],
```

And for the production, there are two ways:

1. passing directly in the webpack configuration:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'SECRET_KEY': '123456'
    },
  }),
],
```

2. fill the server environment variable. for a simple Linux server I prefer to use `export SECRET_KEY=123456`, but for Heroku read [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

**Hint**: In other cases like using Docker or Kubernetes it is needed to use image or cluster configuration file to pass environment variables.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Once I put the dotenv with process.cwd() that made it run. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#config) of *dotenv*, you don't use the *config* method which reads and parses the content from your `.env` file.

By the way, since you're dealing with the webpack, I'd suggest using the [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) package. The given documentation shows an example of the basic configuration along with some other feasible arguments.

If you're interested in other ways of setting up environment variables specifically in React, I recommend [this link](https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5) well-detailed article.

Comment: Thanks I actually am using dotenv-webpack. Works locally but not in production for some reason!

Comment: Have you tried looking into the logs generated by Heroku? Isn't there any specific detail that could tell more about the error you get? I can't believe that dotenv-webpack doesn't work in production, there should be something that interferes the deployment.