# Environment variables in webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

When using Create React App (which uses webpack internally), we can specify environment variables in the scripts section of `package.json`, for example:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "build:a": "REACT_APP_ENV=version-a react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
    "build:b": "REACT_APP_ENV=version-b react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build"
  },
```

These environment variables are then available at runtime as follows:

```
// Logs "version-a" or "version-b", depending on which script was used to build the app
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_ENV);
```

How can I achieve the same functionality in a project that does *not* use Create React App?

---

Here's my version:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "serve:production": "REACT_APP_ENV=version-a && webpack --config ./bundler/webpack.prod.js && serve ./dist -l 4000",
  },
```

I am running on macOS. I have tried both zsh and bash. I am using webpack (v5.88.2). The result of logging `process.env.REACT_APP_ENV` is always `undefined`.

Environment variables that I set in `.env` files work just fine; I use the `dotenv-webpack` plugin for that. The problem is specifically with the environment variables set in `package.json` (as shown above).

Comment: CRA uses the [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) (I wrote a bit about using it [here](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/wiki/Dotenv#client-environment-variables)).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing environment-dependent variables in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030031/passing-environment-dependent-variables-in-webpack)

Comment: @jonrsharpe No, it does not. I want to set the environment variable in package.json as shown in my question. And I want to be able to access it from anywhere, not just in the webpack config file.

Comment: It doesn't matter _where_ the environment variable comes from. And what do you mean "anywhere"? The _actual environment_ is only exposed to code running server-side in the Node environment, the proposed dupe shows how to take that and inject it into the bundled code running client-side (with [some limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76440819/3001761)). Which is exactly what CRA does, which is what you asked, so it's hard to see why you think otherwise.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You have linked to a question with currently 19 answers. I am looking for a solution specific to my problem. I am asking how to replicate what CRA does, such that the two specific code examples shown in my question work as they would in CRA.

Comment: ...and the first option in the accepted answer is [_exactly how CRA/react-scripts does it_](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/0a827f69ab0d2ee3871ba9b71350031d8a81b7ae/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L648-L653), as I mentioned above, so you don't have to scroll too far. If you've had a _specific problem_ trying to apply that to your current setup, please [edit] to give a [mre] _of that_.

Comment: For `dotenv-webpack` specifically (which _also_ [uses the define plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack#limitations)) you need to set the relevant option to allow env vars _not_ loaded from the `.env` file, per [its docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack#properties) and as covered in e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54261938/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/69340880/3001761

Comment: Thanks, so the code you link to in CRA's webpack.config.js, `new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),` depends on at least two other files, env.js and paths.js, which are relevant for the `env` variable, namely ` const env = getClientEnvironment(paths.publicUrlOrPath.slice(0, -1));`. However, `publicUrlOrPath`  comes from `react-dev-utils`. I don't have that in my project. So this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Regarding "the first option in the accepted answer", using the define plugin: This appears to show how to hardcode one specific environment variable with one specific value in the webpack config file. What I want to do is set the value of the environment variable in package.json, *not* in the webpack config file.

Comment: Regarding `dotenv-webpack`, I have tried using the `systemvars: true` option. But that makes no difference for me. `new Dotenv({ path: './env/.env.production', systemvars: true }),`.

Comment: You keep missing the point. No, you can't just copy-paste wholesale from CRA. Yes, the dupe only shows one example. But they both (and the package you're using, and as I keep saying) use `DefinePlugin`. That's how you pass values from the Webpack config file (running in Node, has access to env vars) to the client bundle (running in browser). If you want to pass through more than one, _define more than one_; the dupe doesn't say one-and-only-one works, it shows the pattern. It doesn't care where the values come from (global environment, set in package file, loaded from `.env`, hard coded, ...)

Comment: Now if using `dotenv-webpack` _as documented_ doesn't work, that's maybe a useful question (or a support request to their GitHub). Show what you're actually doing (you're presumably _not_ using react-scripts) and log out `process.env` in the Webpack file (to see if the value is getting that far at least). But you can also just do it yourself; use `dotenv` to add to the real `process.env`, then load up the define plugin (_based on_ how CRA does it, for example - that's what I show in the wiki I linked).

Comment: Just to add, doing the following logs `test`, so I wonder if the problem is with the environment variable getting set in the Terminal environment? `new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'process.env.REACT_APP_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_ENV || 'test') }),`

Comment: And yes, what I actually do is `"serve:production": "REACT_APP_ENV=version-a && webpack --config ./bundler/webpack.prod.js && serve ./dist -l 4000",`

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the logging. If I log `process.env` in my webpack config file, it does *not* contain `REACT_APP_ENV`. So I assume the problem is that the environment variable never gets set from the Terminal for some reason.

Comment: That's because you're using `&&`, which is **not** what you showed in the `react-scripts` equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @jonrsharpe. Removing the `&&` solved it for me. I can also confirm that `DefinePlugin` is not needed, but `systemvars: true` in `Dotenv` is needed. Alternatively, we can manually define each env var using `DefinePlugin`, and then can set `systemvars: false` in `Dotenv`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here's a simple example of how I always use it. As you can see, I'm using the plugin `dotenv-webpack`.

```
const path = require('path');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

const filename = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '' : `.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`;

module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'none',
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
      path: `./src/environments/environment${filename}.env`,
    }),
  ],
  entry: {
    app: ['./src/index.js'],
  },
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
    filename: 'src/index.min.js',
  },
};
```

my environment files are:

- `/src/environments/environment.development.env`
- `/src/environments/environment.production.env`

and here are my package.json script section:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./src/index.js --config nodemon.json",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
```

For using the environment variables `NODE_ENV`, I am using the package `cross-env`, so can I use this under Linux and Windows as well:

---

Otherwise the following article might help you: [How to set NODE_ENV to production/development in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198310/how-to-set-node-env-to-production-development-in-os-x)

Comment: The OP is _also_ using `dotenv-webpack`, and this answer doesn't fix the problem they're having with it.

Comment: This answer put me on the right track, thanks! My problem was that in my script, I used `&&` between setting the environment variable and calling webpack. I did `"serve:production": "REACT_APP_ENV=version-a && webpack (...)",` but it needs to be `"serve:production": "REACT_APP_ENV=version-a webpack (...)",`. This works with and without adding `cross-env` at the front. Edit: I see @jonrsharpe has commented this as well now.

Comment: @Ben which is (still!) not actually in the question - with a MRE this would have been solved a day ago.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have updated my question.